# Module installed using pip, but not found in python

Tags: python, pandas, module

Installed calplot:

```bash
$ pip install calplot
Requirement already satisfied: calplot in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.1.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from calplot) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from calplot) (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1 in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from calplot) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas>=1->calplot) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas>=1->calplot) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas>=1->calplot) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->calplot) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->calplot) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->calplot) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->calplot) (4.39.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->calplot) (9.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->calplot) (23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib->calplot) (1.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas>=1->calplot) (1.16.0)
```

- CalPlot.py

```py
import calplot
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(sum(map(ord, 'calplot')))
import pandas as pd
all_days = pd.date_range('1/1/2019', periods=730, freq='D')
days = np.random.choice(all_days, 500)
events = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(days)), index=days)
calplot.calplot(events)
```

- Executing python program:

```bash
$ python CalPlot.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lamy/Documents/Git/Cs/Architecture/ArchitectureSrc/Hardware/Memory/Harddisk/Backup/Borg/Src/CalPlot.py", line 10, in <module>
    import calplot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calplot'
```

### Any suggestions?

---

### Edit

```bash
type pip
pip is /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pip
pip is /usr/bin/pip
pip is /bin/pip

$ type python
python is aliased to `python3'
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /bin/python

$ type python3
python3 is /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
python3 is /bin/python3

$ python --version
Python 3.11.2

$ pip --version
pip 23.0.1 from /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
$ python -m pip --version
pip 23.0.1 from /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
```

Comment: Is pip tied to that python?  What if you try `python -m pip install calplot`?

Comment: Yes that worked. Can you please suggest why is the pip not tied to the python? Please see the EDIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword python is usually associated with the default version of python installed on your system. If you are using a Linux distro or Mac, this most likely python 2.7.

It therefore means you probably have two versions of python on your system. In this case you will need to be specific on the version of python associated with the library you installed. SO modify your command:

```
python3.10 CalPlot.py
```

Comment: `$ python --version
Python 3.11.2`, I have only 1 version of python. Please see the EDIT.

Comment: Your installation was for 3. 10. `Requirement already satisfied: calplot in /home/lamy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.1.7.5)`